# Python - How to add values to first column and appending

Tags: python, csv

So I have a small script that looks pretty much:

```
for _ in range(3):
    with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(["SN", "Name", "Contribution"])
        writer.writerow([1, "Linus Torvalds", "Linux Kernel"])
        writer.writerow([2, "Tim Berners-Lee", "World Wide Web"])
        writer.writerow([3, "Guido van Rossum", "Python Programming"])

sys.exit()
```

which basically write at this something like:

[image: Bad]

However what I would like to do is to have something like:

[image: Done]

and here basically what I can see for issue is:

1. If there is no csv called test.csv then we create one and add the `Column-1, Column-2, Column-3` only once at top.
2. If there is already a test.csv then we don't need to add the first column `Column-1, Column-2, Column-3`but instead just appending into those column that is needed.

And I am not sure how I am able to do that. I would like to know how to do that.

Comment: maybe you can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSV** stands for 'Comma-separated values'. If you can't see your separated values as **separated columns** you should change your csv viewer delimiter settings (for Excel see [here](https://www.adinstruments.com/support/knowledge-base/how-can-comma-separated-list-be-converted-cells-column-lt)).

also you can put your `for` loop inside the `open` block to don't write your headers in every iteration

It is easier to use `DictWriter` instead of `writer` like this:

```
with open('names.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for _ in range(3):
        writer.writerow({'A': 'SN', 'B': 'NAMES', 'C': 'Contribution'})
        writer.writerow({'A': '1', 'B': 'Linus Torvalds', 'C': 'Linux Kernel'})
        # and so on
```

Comment: The problem here is that everything is saved into one columns as I can see through this example. Basically everything is stored at column A

Comment: Also if you throw this into a `for _ in range(3):` it will write the A B C everytime it opens it up aswell.

Comment: what is your software to see `.csv` files ?

Comment: Microsoft Excel - Im not sure if its any different?

Comment: I think you should set your delimiter character in Excel try this: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4754-convert-csv-to-columns.html

Comment: or this one : https://harvestmedia.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023978031-Opening-Excel-files-with-the-correct-CSV-list-separator

Comment: Right but I do think the problem once again is that everytime I am willing to write the csv you gave for example, it will always add the fieldnames A B C and I just want to do it once at the top when the file is created.

Comment: Oh okey, I think I do understand now what to do actually. Make more sense now. Maybe was my mistake to say CSV instead of excel? But I think converting should be easy fix

Comment: If it solved your problem please accept the answer for future readers.